# Different versions of workflows being fired at the same time

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We have a Dev server in which we then move the solution across to Live to apply any updates that we have done.

We created workflow that sends an email on a trigger of a field change about a year ago. Since then we have made various changes to they way the email works and have been through several solution moves to live.

The last one we did however is now firing two workflows on the trigger, one being the most recent workflow we have updated and the other is the same workflow but about 10 versions back.

I have restarted the Async Processing Service, rebooted the server a couple of times and deactivated then reactivated the workflow.

We are currently using Dynamics 2013 On-Prem.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Sounds like corrupt data in your database. Do some analysis on the Workflow table. Columns ActiveWorkflowId, ParentWorkflowId, StatusCode and Name should give you an idea.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen I just took a look at them columns plus a few extra, the only active ones are the parent and the most up to date, the parent then has the most up to date as the ActiveWorkflowId. Any other ideas as i am all out?

Comment: Your workflow is triggered by a field change about a year ago. Can it be the workflow 10 versions back is simply an instance that has been in a waiting state for many months? Imagine that every update on the field triggers a new workflow instance that will join other waiting instances.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen Although the workflow is triggered on the update of a field, these are all new records so its not possible that an old workflow has been sat in a waiting state

Comment: I'm afraid I am out of ideas...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to delete the system workflow step in MS CRM 2016 on-premise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59767352/not-able-to-delete-the-system-workflow-step-in-ms-crm-2016-on-premise)