# Not able to delete the system workflow step in MS CRM 2016 on-premise

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have created a system workflow and deleted the workflow itself long back. But still the workflow is running. I cannot find it under normal process. But when I do the advanced find for process entity, I can find the workflow. 
When I am open it there is not delete or deactivate button for it.

I tried deleting or deactivating it from the workflow view itself. But it is not allowing me do. Getting the generic error as "Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support" .
Could you please help on this. As this work has few email sending steps, so triggering the emails which I want to stop.

I cannot find it under the setting, all process.

> [image]

But I can find it when I look for the process, use the “New” view and delete all the predefined conditions. In the below screen I click on the result able to find the workflow.

> [image]

Workflow image

> [image]

Comment: could you please add some screenshot for the issue like process view where you see this workflow, workflow itself, so that it will help to give some hints

Comment: @AnkUser added the screenshots.

Comment: ok you say you can see this workflow under advanced find and cannot deactivate or delete it? can we see the screenshot of that workflow itslef?

Comment: Added the workflow screenshot.

Comment: quick question, The user you are using does have system admin rights? if not get system admin right for the user you are using

Comment: Yes the user i am using has the system admin rights.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206066/discussion-between-ankuser-and-priya-biswal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in the below blog was not able to delete those activation type workflows from UI.
https://sachinbansal.blog/2018/05/02/error-while-deactivating-workflows-should-be-exactly-1-messageprocessingstep-registered-for-workflow-dynamics-365/

We have on-premise CRM, so deleted the workflow from CRM database. It is working fine now.
Before deleting the workflow took full database backup. Run the select query by proving the workflow GUID.
After finding the matching workflow record, deleted them from database. In my case I have found the matching records from the below list of tables in the database.

1. WorkflowDependencyBase
2. WorkflowBase
3. WorkflowBaseIds

Answer (score 2):

There are two types are Workflow records - `Definition` & `Activation` (I'm ignoring `Template` in this scenario)

> [image]

For every workflow, two entries will be there. [You can use my query to check in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46125595/7920473).

> [image]

One will have option to `Deactivate` and the other one don't have.

> [image]

You are seeing the `Activation` snapshot record used for execution of WF for lifetime. Take care of those which are already triggered.

> If you look at the schema for the Type attribute, there are three values:
>
> 1 = Definition
>   Definition of a Workflow that is displayed in the application in the "All Processes" view. When you make changes to a workflow, you are making a change to a Workflow definition (or template); if you delete a workflow, you are deleting a workflow definition (or template)
>
> 2 = Activation
>   Whenever you activate (or publish) a workflow, an Activation record is created. An activation represents a snapshot of the workflow definition taken at activation time. If a Workflow is triggered, the System Job (asyncoperation) links back to the Workflow Activation record. Imagine you activate a workflow, a workflow is triggered and is in the midst of running, when you deactivate the workflow and make a change. In order to not effect the currently running Workflow, it uses the Workflow Activation record. If the workflow is triggered again, it will use the new definition (or workflow activation).
>
> 3 = Template
>   If you mark a Workflow as a Workflow Template, it will show up on the new Workflow dialog. If you choose to use a template, a copy of the template will be used as a basis of the Workflow.
>
> **When a Workflow is deleted from the system, the definition is deleted. However, if the workflow was ever published the Activation will remain for a period of time. Once all of the System Jobs that reference a particular Workflow Activation have completed and have been cleaned up (occurs through a recurring daily bulk delete job), the Workflow Activation will also be deleted.**

[Reference](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b717ae4a-1e5d-48d2-880e-c961ff9a776d/crm-2011-workflows-being-duplicated?forum=crm)

Comment: Thank you for your in detail answer.I can find it under process type is activation. Is there any way to delete it. As we have created another new workflow with modified email template. Now the issue is we can not modify the old one. Now both old and new are triggering.

Comment: @PriyaBiswal are you sure it’s still triggering for new instances? Read the very last lines of my answer for clarity

Comment: Vinad- Yes I have deleted all the related system jobs. Deleted the old and new workflow flow and also waited for 24 hours but still the workflow activation did not cleaned up. As we have on-premise crm, deleted the activation workflow from data base.